# Regexmatch certain characters and ends with

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match pieces starting with "[", containing "hi" and ending with "|]".

Input: [he] [picks] [him.|]

Match: [him.|]

Input: [it's] [his|] [word.|]

Match: [his|]

I got started with `\[\S*?\|\]`, but I don't know how to add the condition that it only needs to match it when it contains 'hi'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say "Starts with `[`, doesn't end with `]`, contains `hi`, doesn't end with `]`, ends with `|]`":

```
\[[^\]]*hi[^\]]*\|\]

\[                    Starts with [
  [^\]]*              Contains no ]
        hi            Contains hi
          [^\]]*      Contains no ]
                \|\]  Ends with |]
```

Examples:

- [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/K6QyK5/1)
- [Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5C%5B%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*hi%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*%5C%7C%5C%5D)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\[[^[]*?hi.*?\|]
\[(?:(?!\|])[^[])*hi.*?\|]
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/3HVYQC/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/3HVYQC/2).

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^[]*?` - zero or more chars other than `[` as few as possible
- `(?:(?!\|])[^[])*` - any char other than a `[` char, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start a `|]` char sequence (this second pattern is more reliable, but is also more complex)
- `hi` - `hi` string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\|]` - `|]` string.